# T-SQL String manipulation

Tags: sql, string, t-sql

in my DB I have a column given paths like :

- \myserver\mydir1\dir2\Atest.txt
- \myserver\mydir1\dir2\Btest.txt

At the end I should update a column with the first character after the last "\" delimiter , therefore "A" and "B" in this example.
How can I get this?

Thanks a lot
Largo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select substring(YourColumn, len(YourColumn)-charindex('\', reverse(YourColumn))+2, 1)
from YourTable
```

You have not specified what DBMS you are using. To make this work you need to have these functions available or something similar.

- [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)
- [len](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)
- [charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)
- [reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx)

Comment: The question title says "T-SQL", which makes SQL Server likely.